# Series with an exponential - Laplace of discrete random variable

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, laplace-transform, poisson-distribution

I'm trying to compute the Laplace transform of a Poisson random variable with parameter $\lambda$.

$E[e^{-tX}] = e^{-\lambda}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} e^{-\lambda t} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$

I don't know how to continue now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be 
$$
\mathbb{E}[e^{-tX}] = e^{-\lambda}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} e^{-{\color{red}kt}} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}
\tag{1}$$
**not**$$
\mathbb{E}[e^{-tX}] = e^{-\lambda}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} e^{-{\color{red}\lambda t}} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}\,.\tag{2}
$$
[*(Can you see why?)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) 
Then, with the correct expression (1), you can continue as
$$
\mathbb{E}[e^{-tX}] = e^{-\lambda}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(e^{-t} \lambda)^k}{k!}
= e^{-\lambda}e^{e^t \lambda} = e^{(e^{-t} -1) \lambda} \tag{3}
$$
as desired.

Comment: OMG I can't believe it. Yes I know why, it's just  the insconscius statiscian rule for the expectation. Thanks so much!

Comment: @andereBen You're welcome.

Comment: I'll accept your answer asap

Comment: Wait, shoudn't be $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(e^{-t} \lambda)^k}{k!}
= e^{e^{-t} \lambda}  $$

Comment: You're right, I forgot a minus sign in the copy-pasting. Fixing it. @andereBen